# Does Tensorflow.js have map_fn equivalent?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to iterate over a `tensor1d` with a simple function of chained `if`s, what looks like a common scenario for `map_fn`. There is some way to run this in GPU?
The use case is a [musical note envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(music)), what consists basicaly in receiving a times postitions and returning intensities based in a conditional function.
The code is basically:

```
import { range } from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

// Envelope parameters
const atack = 2;
const decay = 3;
const sustain = 0.4;
const release = 4;

const offset = 1;
const noteDuration = 6;

function envelopeCallback(position:number) {
  if (position <= offset) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (position <= atack) {
    return (position - offset) / atack;
  }
  if (position <= decay) {
    const interpolation = (position - offset - atack) / decay;
    return 1 - interpolation * (1 - sustain);
  }
  const sustainTime = noteDuration - atack - decay;
  if (position <= sustainTime) {
    return sustain;
  }
  if (position <= release) {
    const interpolation = (position - noteDuration) / release;
    return sustain - interpolation * sustain;
  }
  return 0;
}

const sampleRate = 44100;
const audioDuration = 1; // second
const positions = range(0, audioDuration, 1 / sampleRate);
const envelope = mapFn(envelopeCallback, positions);
```

Comment: Are you asking for the `map_fn` equivalent or how to run this on the GPU?

Comment: a way to run this on GPU. I suposed this is a map_fn equivalent

Comment: Are you on browser or Node?

Comment: I am on browser

Comment: You can switch to GPU by using webGL. So you're looking for a map_fn that runs on GPU?

Comment: Yes, but I could only find the map_fn in TF python not in TF js

Comment: what is your use case? i don't think there is such built-in function in tfjs, but it kind of goes against principles. for example, if you want to perform an op on some values that satisfy condition, filter them using `tf.where` instead of checking each value individually.

Comment: I'm making a [music envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(music)), what consists basicaly in receiving a times postitions and return a intensity based in a conditional function.

Comment: I've added the code on the question